# Replace parameter stripping a space it shouldn't

Tags: regex, powershell

I do have an understanding problem with the following replace statement.

```
'Select {0}' -replace '[^\\](\{0\})', 'Success'
```

I would expect : **Select Success**

Instead, the result is: **SelectSuccess**

The `'[^\\](\{0\})'` pattern can be deconstructed in the following way :

- Match a single character NOT in the list '\'
- Match the pattern inside and capture its match

  - Match the character '{' literally
  - Match the characters '0' literally
  - Match the character '}' literally

If I do remove the **Not** section `[^\\]`. then the result become again **Select Success**

Am I missing something ?

Comment: The space **IS** matched by the `[^\\]` The capture group is irrelevant here as you don't use it (neither as a backref nor in the replacement).

Comment: Did you use ``[^\\]`` to avoid matching escaped `{`? But what about ``\\{0}``? It should be changed because the `{` is not escaped, the backslash is, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My question was me not picking up on the fact a "not capture group" was a capture group (Now that I say it like that, it sound obvious :D) That being said, you raised a valid concern. Now that I do a conditional replace based on the presence of "not backslash" in front of it, I am in a situation where I cannot legitimally have a backslash and the thing parsed to end up with ```Select \Parsed``` My current solution — based on the question asked — will have me ending up with ```Select \{0}```. It's what I asked for... but it causes the problem you just highlighted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am looking around in an attempt to solve this second problematic but if you have a cooked up answer, let me know. I think it warrant a separate question directed to that specific issue but I will gladly create a new one. (I might end up doing that in any cases but I will research a bit further on my end before)

Comment: Just use `'(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)\{0\}'`. I do not think it should be a separate question.

Comment: That's just perfect. Using : ```'Select \\\{0}' -replace '(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)\{0\}', 'Success' -replace '\\\\', '\' -replace '\\{', '{'``` , I now get the final desired result under all uses cases.

Comment: @SagePourpre You may unescape all escaped chars with one go, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464919/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) points out in a comment, the problem is that `[^\\]` matches the space character before `{0}`, so that the complete match being replaced is  `{0}`, which explains why the result is `SelectSuccess`.

The solution is to use a [negative look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
Select {0}' -replace '(?<!\\)\{0\}', 'Success'
```

`(?<!\\)` ensures that subexpression `\{0\}` is not (`!`) preceded by (`(?<...`) a `\` char. (`\\`) *without including that char. in the match*.

As LotPings also points out, your use of a capture group (`(...)`) in the regex has no effect, because you're neither referring to it as a backreference inside the regex (`\1`) itself nor in the replacement operand ( `$1`).

Note that `-replace` always replaces what the regex captures *as a whole*, irrespective of capture groups. To match parts of the input without including them in the captured result, use [look-around assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Editor's note: This answer shows a general string-formatting technique available in PowerShell, but its use is not an option in the OP's specific case, because *conditional* string replacement is needed.</sup>

Were you aware  operator.of `-f` . PowerShell has the capability to do string formatting like in .net.

example:-

```
'Select {0}' -f 'Success'

'Select {0} {1}' -f 'All','Files'
```

Refer below article for understanding how its done in .Net, same can be done using `-f`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Answer (score 1):

You want to do two things:

- Find `{0}` that is not starting with an escaped `{` taking into account that there can be a `\\` before `{` denoting a literal backslash (use `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)\{0\}` regex and replace with `Success`)
- "Unescape" all escaped chars where the escape char is a literal backslash (use `(?s)\\(.)` regex and replace with `$1`)

Use

```
'Select \\\{0}' -replace '(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)\{0\}', 'Success' -replace '(?s)\\(.)', '$1'
```

**Pattern 1 details**

- `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)` - a positive lookbehind that, immediately to the left of the current location, requires

  - `(?<!\\)` - no `\` allowed immediately  to the left of the current location
  - `(?:\\{2})*` - 0 or more repetitions of double backslashes
- `\{0\}`  - a `{0}` string.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%7b2%7d%29*%29%5c%7b0%5c%7d&i=Select+%5c%5c%5c%7b0%7d+%7b0%7d&r=Success).

**Pattern 2 details**

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` option that enables `.` to match newlines
- `\\` - a literal backslash
- `(.)`  - Capturing group 1: any char (it will be put back into the resulting string after the match has been replaced).

See  [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%5c%5c%28.%29&i=Select+%5c%5c%5c%7b0%7d+Success&r=%241).